# Child window open inside of the main window form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

I have create a project with one main form window and also i have to use a number of other forms as well.
now i want to open these other forms inside the main window and not outside.
I'm using Visual Studio .NET 2010 as developing environment.
is there anyone who can assist me on this?
Thanks

Comment: Dear Luke, i'm working on windows forms, yes the windows forms.

Comment: today i'm facing a new issue. I have in my parent form one menu bar and one status strip bar, that is what i want is to see in the status bar an icon of the child form when it is shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [MDI child forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329%28VS.71%29.aspx). Tutorial can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx).

It has been existed since VS 2003 even in VB6. It should be available too for VS2010 (I have not tried VS2010 myself).